# How to get marker position which i previously assign? ios swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I assign some value to show marker in google maps. When I click the marker I want to pass the data of this marker assign value to another Controller.

```
class MapsViewController: UIViewController {
    var title_map : String = ""
    @IBOutlet weak var googleMapsview: GMSMapView!
    var geosearch : [Geosearch]?
    private var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
       // self.map_api_call()
       // self.barDesign()
        googleMapsview.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        
        markNearArea()
        
    }
    func markNearArea(){
        for index in 1...(geosearch?.count)! {
        
        let lat  = geosearch?[index-1].lat
        let long  = geosearch?[index-1].lon
        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat! , longitude: long!)
        
        let locationMarker = GMSMarker(position: coordinate)
        locationMarker.map = self.googleMapsview
        locationMarker.title = geosearch?[index-1].title
        locationMarker.appearAnimation = .pop
        locationMarker.icon = UIImage(named: "map_br.png")
        locationMarker.opacity = 1
                                            
                                        }
    }
  
}
```

I want to click marker and want to pass geosearch[position]

```
extension MapsViewController: GMSMapViewDelegate {

    func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool
    {

        
        let url = "https://abk.com/?loc=\(String(describing: geosearch![marker.].pageid!))"
        if let url = URL(string: url ), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
           if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
              UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
           } else {
              UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
           }
        }
        
        return true
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get a marker position by this

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    let position = marker.position
        
    return true
}
```

Or if you want other data then use the `userData` property of `GMSMarker`. like this

First assign data to marker :

```
locationMarker.userData = //Assign your any type of data
```

And inside the delegate

```
func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    let position = marker.position
        
    let markerData = marker.userData // Your marker data
    
    return true
}
```

Comment: i want to get geosearch?[index-1] position

Comment: You can get a direct marker location that is assigned in the markNearArea function, no need again find a location from an array. Still, if you need index of marker then use my second approach to pass index into the userData and in delegate get index from marker.userData.